# How to pass the name of the property that should be changed to a function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

The problem:

I have Preferences struct:

```
struct Preferences {
    var tableSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    var fontSize: CGFloat = 48.0
}
```

And i have PreferencesProvider class that knows all about persistence and should have a methods to control the Preferences object:

```
changeTableSize(withValue: CGSize)
changeFontSize(withValue: CGFloat)
```

The problems is that there are a lot of parameters in the real Preferences and i don’t want to create a method in PreferencesProvider for every property in Preferences struct.

One of the solutions i see is to do the following:

1. Create changeParam(paramName:value) method
2. Create PreferencesParameter enum
3. Switch through enum items to and set corresponding property in Preferences object

Like this:

```
enum PreferencesParameter {
    case TableSize
    case FontSize
}

struct Preferences {
    var tableSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    var fontSize: CGFloat = 48.0
}

func changeParameter(param: PreferencesParameter, value: AnyObject) {
    let prefs = Preferences()   
    switch PreferencesParameter {
        case .TableSize:
            prefs.tableSize = value
        case .FontSize:
            prefs.fontSize = value
     }
}
```

This solution is kinda awkward and my internal perfectionist doesn’t want to code something like this. I’m sure Swift provides a better way to do this but i don’t see it.

Could you please advise me a better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your real problem is that you want to "do something" when the preferences change. So your functions would look something like

```
final class PreferencesProvider {
    var prefs: Preferences
    func syncPreferences() { ... }

    func changeTableSize(withValue: CGSize) {
        prefs.tableSize = withValue
        syncPreferences()
    }

    func changeFontSize(withValue: CGFloat) {
        prefs.fontSize = withValue
        syncPreferences()
    }
}
```

Or something like that. And you don't like all these highly-duplicative functions. (If this isn't your problem, it's not clear why `PreferencesProvider` would need to own the `Preferences` struct at all. It could just provide "fetch" and "store" methods for the struct, and maybe "lock" and "unlock".)

That's easy to fix, though, using `didSet`. Structs are value types. Modifying any part of them modifies the entire struct. This means that if you modify a property of a struct property, the struct property is modified. For example:

```
final class PreferencesProvider {
    var prefs = Preferences() {
        didSet { syncPreferences() }
    }

    func syncPreferences() { ... }
}
```

Now, you just use it as:

```
provider.prefs.tableSize = 1
```

And `syncPreferences()` will run.

Comment: Thanks Rob, didn’t know about didSet.

Some details:
I have isolated the business logic from the ViewController class to the Provider class. My ViewController class doesn’t know anything about the Preferences, all it knows is it should signal that some parameter has changed. That is the reason why i don’t want to directly call the preferences object like this:
provider.prefs.tableSize = 1

Comment: I'm not clear here on what `ViewController` knows about. Does it know about the provider? Is it posting notifications? Is it ok for the ViewController to know about the enum, but not about the struct (that seems very odd). Who calls "changeParameter" in your current code, and how?

Comment: It is complicated :(. I'm adopting Clean Architecture for iOS, so i have the following classes: ViewController with input and output interfaces, it knows only how to signal about changes. Interactor with input and output interfaces, it knows about business logic and owns PersistenceProviders. Presenter, which serves as adapter of interfaces between ViewController and Interactor. So i need a way to signal from ViewController to Presenter that the ViewModel has changed in some universal form. Actually, i found the solution in Uncle Bob talks, will write answer about it later. Thanks.